# C# to Java Jump

Tags: c#, java, .net

I am a c# coder which came up throught the ranks of vb,vfp,fox, and dbase... I am considering on making the jump over to java, to expand my skillset. I don't really see any books on making this jump. I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction on where to begin, and what to study.

Comment: Hmm...first and foremost, forget everything you've learned to love about LINQ.

Comment: Then forget everything you've learned about properties, indexers, events, structs, enums, generics, delegates, lambdas ...

Comment: And those lovely well implemented generics...

Comment: Forget how you did your `get {}` and `set{}` in C# and learn java's getters/setters. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Java is very, very similar to C# (but no LINQ, badly implemented generics, better enums etc). I managed the jump in less than a day, using this information:

- [Java vs C# Code for Code Comparison](http://www.javacamp.org/javavscsharp/)

Answer (score 0):

Why not Read:

- [Joshua Bloch - Effective Java, 2nd Edition](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/)

Java and C# are mostly similar. You will get the hang of it in no time at all....

Answer (score 0):

Hey buddy, c# and java are much similar, but java is less user friendly but more compatible infact its machine independent. But if you wanna earn money stay with c# and .net as they are going to be our industry future and earn more for us. As time is money and we easily make c# applications faster, so enjoy and stick with c#.

Comment: What do you mean exactly, "Java is less user friendly" ? Besides, it's not like JEE-jobs were hard to find.

Comment: Your answer might be accurate financially, but are you advocating never learning anything outside your usual? I think the more languages you learn, the better programmer you are.

Comment: Java jobs where I am from are better than .net ones. So this sounds a little bit fishy...